# 2D dictionaries in go?

Tags: dictionary, go

I have a bit of a dilemma that I've been working on for a bit. I have a 4x4 grid of letters, some of which can be duplicates. Here's an example:

```
a h t l
s n o a
e f s t
w a s e
```

I currently use a 2d array `board[y][x]` to get values. Then I go through the grid (based on an unrelated algorithm) and append letters to make a word. I can't have the *same letter in the same position* twice in a string, but I can have duplicate letters in the event there are others of that letter. I've tried using a dictionary, but if I have three letter "a" values all with different IDs, how does my program know which "a" is which?

My ideal model would be something like a matrix from calculus, but I have no clue how I would implement that in code.

[Matrix example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p0DJ.png)

This way I could reference the ID and that letter if I have the x and y. I think this would be like a 2D dictionary, but I don't even know if those exist. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Your `board[y][x]` could store a pair of (char, id) instead of just the char.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need, but how do I code that? I'm guessing this is like a Pair or Tuple from a different language where I could store two values for each value in the grid, but I've never used or heard of those in Go. Do you have resources or a sample you could point me to?

Comment: Also, the pair (x, y) IS the id of a char. So when building your string, you could take note of which x,y you already used. It is trivial to convert pair x,y into a simple integer, for easier storage/tracking, so you could have a `map[uint8]bool` for tracking usage.

Comment: A pair or tuple is exactly what I was thinking of. In Go, those are generally expressed with a struct, I think. Go structs are quite well documented. Here, for example: https://gobyexample.com/structs

Comment: I think I figured it out. I can make a 2D array of `type gridValue struct` which stores character and ID, then recall either when needed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I wanted to try doing this with a `map[struct{X, Y uint8}]rune` and it came together pretty well.  Found words like `toss`, `safes`, `setal`.  https://github.com/farrellit/stackoverflow/tree/main/68591907